# Mocking AngularJS services with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I seem to be having trouble mocking out my service in my controller.  Specifically 'momentsService'.  Here is my test code.

```
describe('Moment Controller', function() {

    var $scope, $controller, momentsService, $ionicContentBanner, core, components, $q, $ionicPopup;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('core'));
    beforeEach(module('components'));
    beforeEach(module('constants'));


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _momentsService_, _$ionicContentBanner_, _core_, _components_, _$q_, _$ionicPopup_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        momentsService = _momentsService_;
        $ionicContentBanner = _$ionicContentBanner_;
        core = _core_;
        components = _components_;
        $q = _$q_;
        $ionicPopup = _$ionicPopup_;

        spyOn(momentsService, 'initializeView');

        $controller = _$controller_('MomentsController', {
            momentsService: momentsService, 
            $scope: $scope, 
            $ionicContentBanner: $ionicContentBanner,
            core: core,
            component: components,
            $q: $q,
            $ionicPopup: $ionicPopup
        });
    }));

it('should initialize', function() {
    console.log("CONTROLLER");
    console.log(momentsService);
    console.log(momentsService.initializeView());
});

});
```

The last 3 console.log keeps giving me undefined for the 'momentsService'.  In the terminal I'm getting 'undefined is not an object' So my service is not being mocked correctly and my test keeps failing.

Controller and dependencies:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app.MomentsController', [])

    .controller('MomentsController', ['momentsService', '$scope', '$ionicContentBanner', 'core', 'components', '$q', '$ionicPopup', MomentsController]);

    function MomentsController (momentsService, $scope, $ionicContentBanner, core, components, $q, $ionicPopup) {
var vm = this;
//Omitted
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help

-Matt

EDIT:
I am using controllerAs syntax if that matters.

EDIT2:
This still isn't working for me despite trying both of your fixes.  momentsService is still undefined.  My code stands as follows:

```
describe('Moment Controller', function() {

    var $scope, $controller, momentsService, $ionicContentBanner, core, components, $q, $ionicPopup;

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('core'));
    beforeEach(module('components'));
    beforeEach(module('constants'));


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _momentsService_, _$ionicContentBanner_, _core_, _components_, _$q_, _$ionicPopup_) {
        var self = this;
        this.$scope = $rootScope.$new();
        this.momentsService = _momentsService_;

        this.$ionicContentBanner = _$ionicContentBanner_;
        this.core = _core_;
        this.components = _components_;
        this.$q = _$q_;
        this.$ionicPopup = _$ionicPopup_;

        spyOn(momentsService, 'initializeView');

        this.$controller = _$controller_('MomentsController', {
            momentsService: momentsService, 
            $scope: $scope, 
            $ionicContentBanner: $ionicContentBanner,
            core: core,
            component: components,
            $q: $q,
            $ionicPopup: $ionicPopup
        });
    }));

    it('should initialize', function() { 
        console.log(this);
        console.log("CONTROLLER");
        console.log(this.momentsService);
        console.log(this.momentsService.initializeView());
    });

});
```

I have tried without the `this` as well since the plunker posted in the comment didn't use it.  If you disregard the `this` the code matches the plunker posted exactly, I just added other dependencies - Which when I comment out it still complains that my service is undefined.  I don't get it.

Edit 3:

'files' in conf.js:

```
  files: [
      'lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js',
      'lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'js/*',
      'bestMoments/*',
      'moments/*',
      'submitMoment/*',
      'myMoments/*',
      'index.controller.js',
      'layout/mainView.directive.js',
    ],
```

Moments.Service.js dependencies:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app.momentsService', [])

    .service('momentsService', ['core', '$q', 'constants', 'awsServices', 'components', 'logger', 'geolocation', momentsService]);

    function momentsService(core, $q, constants, awsServices, components, logger, geolocation){
```

File structure:
[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/s37266LL/2/

Comment: Your plunker didn't work for me, can you check my new code?

Comment: what module is moments service registered in.

Comment: app.moments.  I've tried to inject app.moments into my test as well and it didn't work.

Comment: what error are you getting? `app.moments` definitely needs to be injected, maybe your karma.conf.js needs to updated

Comment: Same error, momentsService is undefined

Comment: what does the `files` property in your karma.conf look like

Comment: also you havent posted the code for moments service

Comment: I posted the file property and part of moment service in order to avoid a wall of text.  What part of the service do you want to see?

Comment: Nvm forget about that. how about your app.js or whatever file you're registering your modules in . Also is www your root folder ?

Comment: Also, if you take out moments service, do the other services get injected.

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/s37266LL/2/. dont know if this helps at all

Comment: Hey!  Thanks for your help thus far.  It seems like it is not hitting my beforeEach loop at all.  Any idea why?

Comment: which one of them isnt getting hit

Comment: My code right now looks like my second edit and its the big beforeEach block that is not getting hit.

Comment: weird. here's my latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bowofola/s37266LL/3/ convert your beforeEach to something like that and see what logs you get

Comment: oh man i just noticed the 'this', please take that out, it'll never work. and then lets go from there.

Comment: I have tried both ways - With and without the 'this'.  Both ways didn't work.  I have copied your code into mine and it fails in the inject line saying expected 'undefined to be defined.  Its not hitting the 'injector hit!' console log.  I'm trying to recreate the issue on your fiddle and I'm having issues making it fail in the specific way its failing for me.

Comment: i understand that. i would imagine there are a number of things wrong but the this is definitely one of them. "expected 'undefined to be defined" would be in the it block and not the inject block

Comment: did you get the `console.log('beforeEach hit!')`

Comment: Yes I indeed did.

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why inject wouldn't work. Can try running your tests in chrome and inspecting the inspect function?

Comment: I'm using a headless browser and running this through the command line.  I will get back to this tomorrow, I must sleep now.  Thanks for your help thus far though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming jasmine2  - notice all lines with `self` which is `this`. Any properties in `beforeXXXX` is available on `this` inside `it` and `afterXXXX`.

In your case the undefined is on console.log is for momentService which is undefined in `it`. That problem is solved by jasmine feature. [Official jasmine 
 - The `this` Keyword](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-The_%3Ccode%3Ethis%3C/code%3E_keyword)

```
describe('Moment Controller', function() {


    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('core'));
    beforeEach(module('components'));
    beforeEach(module('constants'));


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _momentsService_, _$ionicContentBanner_, _core_, _components_, _$q_, _$ionicPopup_) {
        var self = this;
        self.$scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var momentsService = self.momentsService = _momentsService_;
        self.$ionicContentBanner = _$ionicContentBanner_;
        self.core = _core_;
        self.components = _components_;
        self.$q = _$q_;
        self.$ionicPopup = _$ionicPopup_;

        spyOn(self.momentsService, 'initializeView');

        self.$controller = _$controller_('MomentsController', {
            momentsService: self.momentsService, 
            $scope: self.$scope, 
            $ionicContentBanner: self.$ionicContentBanner,
            core: self.core,
            component: self.components,
            $q: self.$q,
            $ionicPopup: self.$ionicPopup
        });
    }));

  it('should initialize', function() { 
      var self = this;
      console.log("CONTROLLER");
      console.log(self.momentsService);
      console.log(self.momentsService.initializeView());
  });

});
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work for me.  Can you look at my edit to see where I went wrong?

Comment: I think your problem may be due to defining `angular.module('app.momentsService', [])` twice. The seconds occurrence shoul dbe `angular.module('app.momentsService')` i.e. not passing the module dependencies so that angular will return the previously created `app.momentService`. If that doe snot help I suggest you create jsfiddle as suggested by @Bowofola and re-create the problem ?

Comment: After some investigation it seems like its not hitting my beforeEach loop at all.  Any idea why?

Comment: Use Chrome or some browser and click Debug - then F12 and see if any errors - ypu can debug in the browser by putting breakpoints.